# How can I pass an argument to a function when I have called it in the href tag

Tags: javascript

I am creating a apraisal web application , Please help me solve this logic/syntax issue : I want to create a table with the cell content as hyperlink , so that when the user clicks on the link it will open a new window to accept data , also it should display the content of the cell clicked on the next page.

**Here is my Javascript code:**

```
row = table.insertRow(-1);

var cell = row.insertCell(-1);

cell.innerHTML = '<a href="#" onclick = func(name);>'+name+'</a>';


function func(name)
        {


            localStorage.setItem("Selectedname",name);

            window.location.href="form_apraise.html";

        }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 'this' as a reference to the cell on which click event is fired.

```
  cell.innerHTML = '<a href="#" onclick = "func(this);">'+name+'</a>';
```

Access the cell value using the element.text

```
   function func(elem)
    {
        var name =elem.text;

        localStorage.setItem("Selectedname",name);

        window.location.href="form_apraise.html";

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one with enable pop 
window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/', '_blank');

Comment: please explain the arguments within the open method

Comment: window.open('your_url', '_black');

Comment: replace window.location line with this line

Answer (score 1):

```
cell.innerHTML = '<a onclick="func("' + name + '");">' + name + '</a>';
```

This should work. You don't really need the href attribute as that's not very useful in this case. Any element responds to an onclick event.

You could also put the parameters in additional attributes:

```
cell.innerHTML = '<a data-name="' + name + '" onclick="func();">' + name + '</a>';
```

Then in your func() you use this.dataset.name
[More on this here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of options here, but I will tell you 3 of them:

1- Normally you could just send the parameter in your URL and that will be handle by your backend, like this: http://www.example.com/viewName/myName an then you could use window.open(URL, '_blank') that will open a new window

2- You could use a Popup window that get the information with AJAX and show the popup window to accept whatever you want to do.

3- You could create your cell with data-name attribute, assign one class to your cell and with any library or by Javascript only assign an event to all the elements with that class, read the attribute and call window.open(URL, '_blank') something like this:

```
<tr><td class="myClass" data-name="Your Name">Your Name</td></tr>
```

In javascript(jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".myClass").click(function(){
     window.open("http://example.com/"+$(this).data("name"),"_blank")
   })
})
```

In your case the easy way is just pass the name as parameter, open a new window and then show the client the information about that name.